# How to set header to all of requests?

Tags: android, retrofit2

In my application I used `Retrofit` for get requests from server.
I want set **header** to all of requests, I write below codes :

```
public class ApiClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://example.com/api/v1.0.0.1/Api/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    public static Retrofit getClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.interceptors().add(interceptor);
        builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Device", "2").build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });

        OkHttpClient client = builder
                .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(client)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

But when run application, not set this header!

How can I it? please help me

Comment: how you know header not set ?

Comment: @SantanuSur, if set this header I should goto main page! if not set this header just show me login page! now just show login page and not go to main page

Comment: show your code..calling class and interface

Comment: @SantanuSur, my interface :     `@POST("user/GetCountries")
    Call<CountryResponse> getCountryList(@Header("Token") String token);`

Comment: but you said its get request

Comment: and your header is already added

Comment: @SantanuSur, do you have skype ID? i'm amateur and really need your help :(

Comment: ya i have jishu777

Comment: @SantanuSur, I sent you PM on skype. please see